# How implement a git Smart HTTP server

Tags: c#, git, protocols, smart-http

I want to implement a git server by Smart HTTP protocol. Any body can give me some reference documents or codes for study. C-style language is better.

Use a the C# language and libgit2sharp implement it is my target.

Comment: If you just want/need to host a Git server accessible using `HTTP[S]` on a Windows platform, may be ["Git Web Access"](http://gitweb.codeplex.com/) is a much simpler way to go? Basically is hosts Git using IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Git itself](https://github.com/git/git/) is a reference implementation done in a C-style language. Looks for files which names contain "http".

Comment: Great, I found it in page https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/receive-pack.c

Answer (score 0):

See GitAspx, using ASP.NET MVC razor + GitSharp,

https://github.com/linquize/git-dot-aspx

Comment: I just want to learn Smart HTTP Protocol. GitSharp is a manual translated from jgit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994205/gitsharp-vs-ngit. If you can give me the references is better.